Sphinx search: How to index dimensions stored as a string as different keywords?
I have big table with materials with description like 'Sheet 10x200...' and so on.
I want to index dimensions as different keywords, so when I type 'sheet 10' I can see all sheets with other dimensions.
I tried with blend_chars, but because it's a normal character (it's a cyrillic 'х') I have to exclude it from charset_table.
My index looks like this:
charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, U+0370..U+03FF, U+0410..U+0424->U+0430..U+0444,U+0426..U+042F->U+0446..U+044F
blend_chars = U+0445

but this breaks indexing of words before dimensions.
